# ASP.NET MVC database connection using a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I have this form and I want it to connect to an external database. I have no idea how to and after a lot of research its still not clear to me.

Here is my code. Any guidance will be helpful.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>User Information</h2>

<p>This is your user information!</p>

<form action="Result">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value=" ">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value=" ">
    <br>
    Role:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Role" value=" ">
    <br>
    Ranking:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Ranking" value=" ">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I don't really know which direction to take this form. Many thanks in advance

Comment: did you use database with your application before?

Comment: no, i have a database set up externally using sql manager, just not sure how to connect the two.

Comment: you need to go to server explorer and make a connection ... then copy the connection string and put it web.config

Comment: There are so many online resources about this that I wonder how you could have missed all of them. Anyway, try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+sql+server+connection or this: https://www.google.com/search?q=learn+asp.net+mvc+database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't connect the actual form itself, you connect your backend to the DB, and you connect the form to your backend.
Make some sort of route to handle the form request and then connect to your database in that route, and use it to input the data to the database.

Related links:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql.html

Comment: oh right ok i understand, ill get onto doing that now. Thanks allot.

Answer (score 0):

Your form should post data to an existing action inside an existing controller, and then, your database db connection already  must be defined in your server-side MVC application.

At your point, probably, your form is looking for something called "Result"...

Now, I think that you are able to keep your research for solutions to your specific case.